# Not getting passed new SoapClient

Tags: php, debugging, soap-client

I am having difficulties trying to figure out what is wrong with this script:

```
echo 'Checkpoint 1';

$client = new SoapClient("http://X.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXX/SessionManagement?singleWsdl", array('exceptions' => 0));

echo 'Checkpoint 2';

$parms['login'] = 'Admin';
$parms['password'] = "";

$result = $client->Connect($parms);

if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    echo 'Has an error!';
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo 'No error!';
}
```

I never get to the "Checkpoint 2"?

I have tried this on my localhost and it works, but not on my live server!?!

My live server has:
Soap Client: enabled
Soap Server: enabled

How do I figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: What happens instead? Is there any error thrown? Does this end in a timeout?

Comment: start by setting error reporting to the highest, most verbose available setting (error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true); just before the SOAPClient instantiation.